# Show that $f(z)=z^Nlog(z)$ is non-analytic at the origin while being differentiable at the origin.

Tags: complex-analysis

I believe I need to show that the Cauchy-Riemann equations for $f(z)$ fails to hold at the origin, but I'm not sure how to do that.

I'm also struggling to show that this function is differentiable at the origin from the limit definition.

Any ideas?

Comment: The Cauchy-Riemann equations are going to be satisfied at the origin for $N\geq 2$. This is because $f$ does have complex derivative at the origin.

Comment: @logarithm so why should f be non-analytic at the origin in this case?

Comment: Well, $\log$ is in principle multi-valued. I suppose some branch of it is implied. Then there is going to be a line of points tending to the origin at which the function is discontinuous. Remember that analytic needs the function to have complex derivative at all points in a neighborhood of the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is analytic at the origin then it would be differentiable in some open disc around $0$.  This implies that $log(z)$ is differentiable at $z$ if $z \neq 0$ and $|z|$ is sufficiently small. But $\log(z)$ is not even continuous at the points $-\frac 1 n$.

I am assuming that you are using the principal branch of logarithm. However, as similar argument works for any branch.